# EntryPointNotFoundException external JS Lib error

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to implement JS library with my C# code.
Is very simple but I am getting this error:

> EntryPointNotFoundException: Test
>   TalkDB.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/TalkDB.cs:30)

C# code is in scripts folder and JS library at plugins/webgl with .jslib extension.
Also read this article, but no idea what I am missing: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html?_ga=1.27144893.1658401563.1487328483

**C# Code:**

```
public class TalkDB : MonoBehaviour
{
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void Test();

    void Start()
    {

        Test();

    }
}
```

**JS Library:**

```
var HighscorePlugin = {
    Test: function()
    {
        window.alert("Testing 1, 2, 3,...");
    }
};

mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, HighscorePlugin);
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer, is quite simple in fact.
I does not work when running locally, just when running from a server.
To prevent this error this should be done:

#if UNITY_WEBGL && !UNITY_EDITOR

[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void Test();
#else

// something else to emulate what you want to do

#endif

And do this also when calling the function.
Happy programming :)

Answer (score 0):

EntryPointNotFoundExceptionmeans means that the function "Test" is either (A) not marked as exportable (not visible) or (B) signature does not match C# definition.

Most likely your issue is the former (A).

I would recommend running DUMPBIN.EXE against your library to verify your "test" function is getting exported and that the its respective signature matches your C# definition.  Could be some code-injection on JS-side.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. I can get library functions when I am writting so I assume is ok that part. Dumpbin.exe works with .jslib?

Comment: You cannot import jslib into .NET via InterOp.  I had assumed your JavaLib has something to facilitate Windows DLL extensions, however that does not appear to be the case.  E.g. If DumpBin does not recognize your library then you will need to wrap your Library with something that support Windows DLL